# Await/Async blocks UI

Tags: c#

I have a very simple app, which actually is just a module for a much larger one, in which I have to process all the paragraphs of a text document. I've written an async method to allow for progress report and not freezing the UI, but none of that works. The progress bar just fills at the end and the UI is blocked during execution.

I've tried both async/await and BackgroundWorker methods, to no avail.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public async Task<string> ReadTextFile()
    {
        string result = null;

        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"C:\Users\Junior\Desktop\asynctest.txt"))
        {
            result = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }

        return result;
    }

    public string[] CreateParagraphs(string text)
    {
        string[] result;

        result = text.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r", "\r\n" },  StringSplitOptions.None);

        return result;
    }

    public List<string> ReplaceGestures(string[] paragraphs, IProgress<int> progress)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        for(int i=0; i < paragraphs.Length; i++)
        {
            paragraphs[i] = paragraphs[i].Replace("+", "(*)");

            if (progress != null && (i % 10 == 0))
                progress.Report(i);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Info.Text = "Reading file...";

        string text = await ReadTextFile();

        Info.Text = "Creating paragraphs...";

        string[] paragraphs = await Task.Run(() => CreateParagraphs(text));

        Info.Text = "Replacing gestures....";

        Bar.Maximum = paragraphs.Length;

        var progress = new Progress<int>(percent =>
        {
            Bar.Value = percent; 
        });

        List<string> paragraphsWithGestures = await Task.Run(() => ReplaceGestures(paragraphs, progress));

        Info.Text = "Done.";
    }
}
```

I am expecting this code to update the progress bar at 10 iteration intervals.

Comment: `result` is never populated inside `ReplaceGestures`

Comment: Yes, I omitted that code. But still, it should not matter for the question at hand.

Comment: Your code [looks fine](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html#progress-reporter-implementation). Are you sure the problem is not in the code you have omitted?

Comment: Nope. Just omitted that bit. The text file es rather large (for testing porpouses), and the UI just blocks.

Comment: I can't see why it would block. How does it block? You can't drag the window around and the button won't animate when you hover the mouse over it? Or just the progress bar fills in one go instead of gradually?

Comment: I cannot move the window and the progress bar just goes from 0 to 100% at the end.

Comment: You could be sending too many progress updates too quickly, locking up the UI b/c its spending all its time redrawing the progress bar. Have you tried less frequent updates?

Comment: Most likely DaveM has identified the problem. I recommend limiting updates by time interval. You can use [ObservableProgress](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/4248e50b4cb52b933c0d) for that.